Android: DatagramPacket does not receive packets in the background using Service and WakeLock
I am making an application for android 5.1, the essence of which is to transfer voice packets over the UDP protocol between devices, however, when I block the screen of the device itself, socket.receive(packet); as if it falls asleep and ignores all incoming packets, although the Player and PlayerThread themselves are working successfully.
Player.java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import ro.ui.pttdroid.codecs.Speex;
import ro.ui.pttdroid.managers.WakeLockManager;
import ro.ui.pttdroid.managers.WifiLockManager;
import ro.ui.pttdroid.settings.AudioSettings;
import ro.ui.pttdroid.settings.CommSettings;
import ro.ui.pttdroid.util.Audio;
import ro.ui.pttdroid.util.IP;
import ro.ui.pttdroid.util.Log;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class Player extends Service
{
    private WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;

    private PlayerThread    playerThread;
    
    private IBinder playerBinder = new PlayerBinder();
    
    private TelephonyManager    telephonyManager;
    private PhoneCallListener   phoneCallListener;
    
    public class PlayerBinder extends Binder 
    {
        Player getService() 
        {        
            return Player.this;
        }
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {        
        playerThread = new PlayerThread();
        playerThread.start();
        
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        phoneCallListener = new PhoneCallListener();
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneCallListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        startForeground(1, createNotification());

        WakeLockManager.acquireWakeLock(this);
        WifiLockManager.acquireWifiLock(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {    
        return playerBinder;
    }   
    
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        playerThread.shutdown();
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneCallListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);

        WakeLockManager.releaseWakeLock();
        WifiLockManager.releaseWifiLock();
    }
    
    public int getProgress() 
    {
        return playerThread.getProgress();
    }

    private Notification createNotification() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.app_running))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notif_icon))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        return builder.build();
    }
    
    private class PlayerThread extends Thread
    {
        private AudioTrack  player;
        
        private volatile boolean running = true;    
        private volatile boolean playing = true;
        
        private DatagramSocket  socket;
        private DatagramPacket  packet;
        
        private short[] pcmFrame = new short[Audio.FRAME_SIZE];
        private byte[]  encodedFrame;
        
        private AtomicInteger progress = new AtomicInteger(0);
        
        public void run()
        {
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
            
            while(isRunning())
            {
                init();

                while(isPlaying()) 
                {                           
                    try
                    {
                        socket.receive(packet); //<--- Problem is Here
                    }
                    catch(SocketException e) //Due to socket.close()
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.error(getClass(), e);
                    }

                    if(AudioSettings.getEchoState()==AudioSettings.ECHO_OFF && IP.contains(packet.getAddress()))
                        continue;

                    if(AudioSettings.useSpeex()==AudioSettings.USE_SPEEX) 
                    {
                        Speex.decode(encodedFrame, encodedFrame.length, pcmFrame);
                        player.write(pcmFrame, 0, Audio.FRAME_SIZE);
                    }
                    else 
                    {           
                        player.write(encodedFrame, 0, Audio.FRAME_SIZE_IN_BYTES);
                    }   

                    progress.incrementAndGet();
                }

                player.stop();
                player.release();
                
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    try 
                    {   
                        if(isRunning())
                            wait();
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e) 
                    {
                        Log.error(getClass(), e);
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
        
        private void init() 
        {   
            try 
            {                       
                player = new AudioTrack(
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
                        Audio.SAMPLE_RATE, 
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, 
                        Audio.ENCODING_PCM_NUM_BITS, 
                        Audio.TRACK_BUFFER_SIZE, 
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);    

                switch(CommSettings.getCastType()) 
                {
                    case CommSettings.BROADCAST:
                        socket = new DatagramSocket(CommSettings.getPort());
                        socket.setBroadcast(true);
                    break;
                    case CommSettings.MULTICAST:
                        socket = new MulticastSocket(CommSettings.getPort());
                        ((MulticastSocket) socket).joinGroup(CommSettings.getMulticastAddr());                                      
                    break;
                    case CommSettings.UNICAST:
                        socket = new DatagramSocket(CommSettings.getPort());
                    break;
                }

                if(AudioSettings.useSpeex()==AudioSettings.USE_SPEEX)
                    encodedFrame = new byte[Speex.getEncodedSize(AudioSettings.getSpeexQuality())];
                else 
                    encodedFrame = new byte[Audio.FRAME_SIZE_IN_BYTES];
                
                packet = new DatagramPacket(encodedFrame, encodedFrame.length);
                
                player.play();
            }
            catch(IOException e) 
            {
                Log.error(getClass(), e);
            }       
        }
        
        private synchronized boolean isRunning()
        {
            return running;
        }
            
        private synchronized boolean isPlaying()
        {
            return playing;
        }
                
        public synchronized void pauseAudio() 
        {               
            playing = false;

            try
            {
                if(socket instanceof MulticastSocket)
                    ((MulticastSocket) socket).leaveGroup(CommSettings.getMulticastAddr());
                socket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.error(getClass(), e);
            }                   
        }
        
        public synchronized void resumeAudio() 
        {
            playing = true;
            notify();
        }
                                    
        private synchronized void shutdown() 
        {
            pauseAudio();
            running = false;
            notify();
        }
        
        public int getProgress() 
        {
            return progress.intValue();
        }

    }
    
    private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
        
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged (int state, String incomingNumber)
        {
            if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)
                playerThread.pauseAudio();
            else if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
                playerThread.resumeAudio();
        }
        
    }
            
}

WakeLockManager.java
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.PowerManager;
public class WakeLockManager {
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    public static final int PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK = 32;

    public static void acquireWakeLock(Context context) {
        if (wakeLock == null) {
            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "pttdroid::WakeLock");
        }
        if (!wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            wakeLock.acquire();
        }
    }

    public static void releaseWakeLock() {
        if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            wakeLock.release();
            wakeLock = null;
        }
    }
}

I used PowerManager.WakeLock and WifiManager.WifiLock wifi Lock, I tried to set timeouts for receive out of desperation, but nothing helped, I tried to change the sound type for AudioTrack and it didn't work either. Please ask if you have any questions, I will be extremely grateful for any advice.
